# changing tooltip bubble size in CSS

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-mobile

I am new to CSS so all I have been doing is playing around and changing various variables of some CSS code to create what I want. Currently, my text is currently displaying outside the bubble but I want it inside. I am not sure how to do this. I believe that I would edit something inside the `.tooltip_body` but I changed all the variables I thought would change the bubble but nothing is changing the way I want it to. Could someone help me or give me a hint with this?

my `tooltip_body`:

```
.tooltip_body {
    display: inline-block;
    white-space:nowrap;
    position: relative;
    background: #000;
    border-radius: 6px;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 4px 4px;
    width: 100%;
}
```

My jsfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/liondancer/rKPfe/7/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply remove `width:100%` from `.tooltip_body`. They are already set to `display:inline-block`, there is no need for `width:100%;` as they are already being forced to contain their children elements.

[**Working jsFiddle here**](http://jsfiddle.net/Gh3sX/)

```
.tooltip_body {
    width:100%; /* remove this */
}
```

Comment: @Liondancer If you want to increase the size, just increase the `padding`.. http://jsfiddle.net/7xGmY/ and http://jsfiddle.net/Gh3sX/2/